# Rewrite a specific Post Format to URL slug

Tags: posts, url-rewriting, urls, post-formats

I'll cut to the chase. I am using Post Formats on my WordPress 3.6 site, specifically 'Video', which I want to include in the URL slug.

I'm pretty well verse in WordPress plugin writing etc, but cannot seem to find a way to ONLY rewrite URLs for this post format.

The rough PSEUDO CODE logic would be

```
if (post_format == 'Video') {
// DO CLEVER REWRITING STUFF
}
```

Would greatly appreciate the help/advice anyone can offer.

Comment: what URL structure do you want for these posts? basically, the two parts of this would be to add a rewrite rule to handle the incoming requests, and add a filter to `post_link` to output the correct URL for any permalink API calls.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Milo. My permalinks are using the mydomain.com/post-title-here style structure, however I want it to be /videos/post-title-here ONLY for 'video' post formats.